# How to code VHDL in one single .vhd file?

Tags: vhdl

I am coding in vhdl and I want to have all my codes in one single file. Here is the code I have in one file (full adder and half adder):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

use work.Single_Bit_Half_Adder; 

entity Single_Bit_Full_Adder is
    Port (
            A :in STD_LOGIC;
            B :in STD_LOGIC;
          Cin :in STD_LOGIC;
          Sum :out STD_LOGIC;
          Cout :out STD_LOGIC
          );
end Single_Bit_Full_Adder;

architecture Behavioral of Single_Bit_Full_Adder is

component Single_Bit_Half_Adder is
    Port (
          A :in STD_LOGIC;
          B :in STD_LOGIC;
          Sum :out STD_LOGIC;
          Cout :out STD_LOGIC
          );
end component;
signal tempSum, tempCoutHA1, tempCoutHA2: STD_LOGIC;

begin

Half_Adder1: Single_Bit_Half_Adder port map (A => A, B => B, Sum => tempSum, Cout => tempCoutHA1);
Half_Adder2: Single_Bit_Half_Adder port map (A => tempSum, B => Cin, Sum => Sum, Cout => tempCoutHA2);  
Cout <= tempCoutHA1 or tempCoutHA2;

end Behavioral;
------------------------------

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Single_Bit_Half_Adder is
    Port (
          A :in STD_LOGIC;
          B :in STD_LOGIC;
          Sum :out STD_LOGIC;
          Cout :out STD_LOGIC
          );
end Single_Bit_Half_Adder;

architecture Behavioral of Single_Bit_Half_Adder is

begin

Sum <= A xor B;
Cout <= A and B;

end Behavioral;
```

But, I am receiving an error on *"use work.Single_Bit_Half_Adder;"* saying that single_bit_half_adder is not in library .

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: At the time the compiler compiles that "use" clause, single_bit_half_adder is not in library exactly as the message says. So if you insist on a single file, place single_bit_half_adder before Single_Bit_Full_Adder. (Then the use clause may be redundant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing because there is no `Single_Bit_Half_Adder` in your library. However the code for it is in your file, so just remove the line `use work.Single_Bit_Half_Adder;` and it should be fine.